# Abstract method with indeterminably method signature

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I have a design problem. I try to write a role playing game where sorcerers fight against each other. They fight against each other by casting spells. I decided to make an abstract super class for all spells.

Basically, a spell is an object that has a name (for example fireball), knows its sorcerer (for determining the strength of the spell by the sorcerers values) and the spell has to be casted, so it should have an abstract method "cast".

```
public abstract class Spell {
    private String name;
    private Sorcerer sorcerer;
    public abstract void cast();
}
```

But now I have a problem: I can not standardize the method signature of this method, because different spells need different parameters and may have different return values. A healing cast can heal the Sorcerer and may not need a parameter. But a fireball-spell for example needs an enemy as a parameter. I would have to define different base-classes for spells. This could lead to an exploding class hierarchy.

Is there a way to define some sort of "spongy methods" to overload? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use varargs. Assuming one spell can only be cast by one sorcerer, it would look something like this:

```
public abstract class Spell {
    private String name;
    public abstract void cast(Sorcerer sorcerer, Target... targets);
}
```

The cast method accepts 1 sorcerer and 0 or more targets (more about varargs on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs).

### The better way

By looking at the example it seems there is always one sorcerer associated with one spell, which is saved to class variable sorcerer (the character that cast the spell). By creating a getter for that sorcerer, it would be possible to simplify the `cast` method signature even more:

```
public abstract class Spell {
    private String name;
    private Sorcerer sorcerer;
    public Sorcerer getSorcerer() {
        return sorcerer;
    }
    public abstract void cast(Target... targets);
}
```

That way it is still possible to access the sorcerer from child classes, but it isn't a part of the `cast` method signature.

If I understood correctly the method should also support different return types. One way to accomplish this would be to create a class (e.g. SpellConsequence), which can hold different values and types. That way SpellConsequence class can be returned from cast method.

Comment: I agree for approach number two to be a good approach, however, I disagree with number one.
In approach number one, you refer to a Sorcerer in your Class as a field, but also refer to a Sorcerer to a sorcerer that might be a Sorcerer that is not the Sorcerer attached to the Object. This might lead to someone else casting the spell, while also having an additional layer of indirection. 
Either remove the Sorcerer from the method or remove it from the Spell class.

Also, as all spells will always have a target (either an enemy or the sorcerer), the use of sorcerer in the method is redundant.

Comment: That's a good point, changed the first approach in my answer. That way, if sorcerer needs to be given to the `cast` method, it won't have to be saved to a class variable.  I agree however, that the second way is the better way to do it.

Comment: I agree with the second way to be the better way as well, thank you for editing your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about `void cast(Sorcerer source, Targetable target)`?
you could `spell.cast(myself, myself)` for heal or `spell.cast(myself, enemyPositionOrWhatever)`.

Comment: And if there are multiple enemies? And what if a spell needs no source or no target?

Comment: I think it is better to let `Spell` compute the area of effect instead of passing in, to make them self contained. When you know your target, you should be able to query the adjacent character I suppose.

Comment: Source could be removed like what @katamb said, if the spell doesn't need the parameter you could simply omit it in concrete class